# Extract between row counts

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I make the following statement extract row 100 to row 200:

```
SELECT Offices.OfficeID, ContractsBooksCommodities.CommodityID
  FROM ((((Offices 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Sales ON Offices.CompanyID = tbl_Sales.CompanyID) 
    INNER JOIN ContractBooks ON tbl_Sales.CompanyID = ContractBooks.CompanyID)      
    INNER JOIN ContractsBooksAds ON ContractBooks.ContractNum = ContractsBooksAds.ContractNum) 
    INNER JOIN ContractsBooksBrands ON ContractsBooksAds.ContractNum = ContractsBooksBrands.ContractNum) 
    INNER JOIN ContractsBooksCommodities ON ContractsBooksBrands.ContractNum = ContractsBooksCommodities.ContractNum;
```

Comment: http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/06/skip-and-take-n-number-of-records-in.html

Comment: I am not using SQL-Server.. I am using MS Access.. would that script still work..?

Comment: They both use Structured Query Language no?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` doesn't work in Access.  There are various other solutions, such as this *[ranking example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208946)*, but they require the records to be unique in some way in order for them to have unique ranks (or row numbers in this case).

Answer (score 0):

This might be slow:

```
SELECT Top 101 Offices.OfficeID, ContractsBooksCommodities.CommodityID
  FROM ((((Offices 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Sales ON Offices.CompanyID = tbl_Sales.CompanyID) 
    INNER JOIN ContractBooks ON tbl_Sales.CompanyID = ContractBooks.CompanyID)      
    INNER JOIN ContractsBooksAds ON ContractBooks.ContractNum = ContractsBooksAds.ContractNum) 
    INNER JOIN ContractsBooksBrands ON ContractsBooksAds.ContractNum = ContractsBooksBrands.ContractNum) 
    INNER JOIN ContractsBooksCommodities ON ContractsBooksBrands.ContractNum = ContractsBooksCommodities.ContractNum
WHERE Offices.OfficeID NOT IN (SELECT Top 99 Offices.OfficeID
  FROM ((((Offices 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Sales ON Offices.CompanyID = tbl_Sales.CompanyID) 
    INNER JOIN ContractBooks ON tbl_Sales.CompanyID = ContractBooks.CompanyID)      
    INNER JOIN ContractsBooksAds ON ContractBooks.ContractNum = ContractsBooksAds.ContractNum) 
    INNER JOIN ContractsBooksBrands ON ContractsBooksAds.ContractNum = ContractsBooksBrands.ContractNum) 
    INNER JOIN ContractsBooksCommodities ON ContractsBooksBrands.ContractNum = ContractsBooksCommodities.ContractNum
ORDER BY Offices.OfficeID, ContractsBooksCommodities.CommodityID) 
ORDER BY Offices.OfficeID, ContractsBooksCommodities.CommodityID
```

I do not know what fields make your sort unique, but that is what you need because MS Access will return matches otherwise.